# How to write a defaultdict(list) values into separate rows in csv file using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, defaultdict

I have the following defaultdict(list) and trying to write its key as the header and its values in separate rows using csv writer.

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Replier Username': ['vindyne8', 'vindyne8', 'denisc', 'denisc', 'vindyne8', 'vindyne8', 'denisc', 'denisc', 'vindyne8', 'vindyne8', 'denisc', 'vindyne8', 'denisc', 'igotBAWS', 'vindyne8', 'vindyne8', 'OneChain', 'denisc', 'denisc', 'vindyne8', 'vindyne8', 'denisc', 'denisc', 'vindyne8', 'denisc', 'denisc', 'vindyne8', 'denisc']})`

I would like to get the following result in the csv file:

```
Replier Username

vindyne8
vindyne8
denisc
denisc
vindyne8
.
.
.
```

I tired the following code but it is writing the key and values in separate columns not separate rows.

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer= csv.writer(f)
    for k,v in replier_username_dict.items():
        writer.writerow([k] + v)
```

Anyone has idea? Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you provide the output to your code so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  You just need to loop through the values since it contains a list.

```
>>> for key, values in replier_username_dict.items():
...     csvwriter.writerow ([key])
...     for value in values:
...         csvwriter.writerow ([value])
... 
Replier Username
vindyne8
vindyne8
denisc
denisc
vindyne8
```